# How to setup global variables in apollo-client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to setup global variable for all `graphql` queries, I am using Apollo-client, which in its setup provides defaultOptions, where I can setup the variables, but mutations and queries in mutation update ignore them.

```
return new ApolloClient({
    connectToDevTools: isBrowser,
    ssrMode: !isBrowser, // Disables forceFetch on the server (so queries are only run once)
    link: new HttpLink({
        uri: GRAPHQL_URL, // Server URL (must be absolute)
        credentials: 'same-origin', // Additional fetch() options like `credentials` or `headers`
        // Use fetch() polyfill on the server
        fetch: !isBrowser ? fetch : undefined,
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || {}),
    defaultOptions: {
        mutate: { variables: { domain: NEW_YORK_GQL_DOMAIN } },
        watchQuery: { variables: { domain: NEW_YORK_GQL_DOMAIN } },
        query: { variables: { domain: NEW_YORK_GQL_DOMAIN } },
    },
});
```

Don't really know what I am doing wrong, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling `ApolloClient.query` with additional variables it will override the default variables entirely. So you should be able to do the following:

```js
const result = await apolloClient.query({
  query,
  variables: {
    ...apolloClient.defaultOptions.query.variables,
    uri
  }
});
```

The hooks such as `useQuery` appear to merge the default variables correctly with any additional variables so shouldn't require this.